# Interfaces monitoring with control

Tags: networking, 20.04, interface, monitoring, network-monitoring

is there any web software that allows you to automatically monitor all interfaces in the local network?
And will he allow them to control, need to be suspended?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "web software"? And what do you want to monitor? I think you have to be much more specific. Focus on this: What specific problem do you need to have solved?

Comment: However, it *sounds* like you might want to look into SNMP monitoring. But read up a little on the topic first. Also, if you're looking for software recommendations, a proper forum might be better suited. Thanks. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Hi, i want to monitoring all intrefaces on server in web application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.